# Как из большого log файла убрать повторы строк?

Tags: python

Мучаюсь с регулярными выражениями уже второй день, ничего не получается. В программировании полный ноль. Как из файла с миллионом строк убрать строки повторы со второго столбика, пишу ACL, в ручную фильтровать очень долго(

Пример:

```
permitted tcp 10.10.20.51(53840) -> 10.10.0.2(389), 1 packet
permitted tcp 10.10.20.150(28426) -> 10.10.0.5(8080), 1 packet
permitted tcp 10.10.20.54(53460) -> 10.10.0.2(389), 1 packet
permitted tcp 10.10.20.54(53462) -> 10.10.0.3(389), 1 packet
permitted udp 10.10.20.54(53793) -> 10.10.0.3(53), 1 packet
permitted tcp 10.10.20.54(53464) -> 10.10.0.5(8080), 1 packet
```

А в результате хочется

```
permitted tcp 10.10.20.51(53840) -> 10.10.0.2(389), 1 packet
permitted tcp 10.10.20.150(28426) -> 10.10.0.5(8080), 1 packet
permitted tcp 10.10.20.54(53462) -> 10.10.0.3(389), 1 packet
permitted udp 10.10.20.54(53793) -> 10.10.0.3(53), 1 packet
```

Comment: обрабатывать большие файлы в Python - не самая лучшая идея. Какая у вас OS?

Answer (score 0):

Пробегаем по строкам файла. Файл будем подавать через стандартный вход. Запускать как-то так: `python filter_duplicates.py < input.txt > output.txt`. Пока это простое копирование:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line, end='')
```

В строках нужно выделить ключи - те части которые мы будем сравнивать для поиска повторений. Я думаю что сравнивать нужно от стрелочки и до конца строки. `->.*` отыскивает стрелочку. `.*` означает "и любые символы". `assert` ломает программу если стрелочки в строке нет. Последняя строка выделяет "от стрелочки до конца":

```
m = re.search('->.*', line)
assert m is not None
key = m.group(0)
```

Ключи надо проверять на повторение. Заведем `keys` - хранилище для ключей, которые мы уже видели. `if key not in keys:` - проверяет что нового ключа там нет. Если это так, печатаем строку и запоминаем ключ на будущее:

```
keys = set()
...

    if key not in keys:
        print(line, end='')
        keys.add(key)
```

Всё вместе:

```
import re
import sys

keys = set()

for line in sys.stdin:
    m = re.search('->.*', line)
    assert m is not None
    key = m.group(0)
    if key not in keys:
        print(line, end='')
        keys.add(key)
```

> ```
> $ cat input.txt 
> permitted tcp 10.10.20.51(53840) -> 10.10.0.2(389), 1 packet
> permitted tcp 10.10.20.150(28426) -> 10.10.0.5(8080), 1 packet
> permitted tcp 10.10.20.54(53460) -> 10.10.0.2(389), 1 packet
> permitted tcp 10.10.20.54(53462) -> 10.10.0.3(389), 1 packet
> permitted udp 10.10.20.54(53793) -> 10.10.0.3(53), 1 packet
> permitted tcp 10.10.20.54(53464) -> 10.10.0.5(8080), 1 packet
>
> $ python filter_duplicates.py < input.txt 
> permitted tcp 10.10.20.51(53840) -> 10.10.0.2(389), 1 packet
> permitted tcp 10.10.20.150(28426) -> 10.10.0.5(8080), 1 packet
> permitted tcp 10.10.20.54(53462) -> 10.10.0.3(389), 1 packet
> permitted udp 10.10.20.54(53793) -> 10.10.0.3(53), 1 packet
> ```

Проверим на файле из миллиона строк:

> ```
> $ wc -lc long_input.txt 
>  1000000 77000000 long_input.txt
>
> $ time python filter_duplicates.py < long_input.txt > long_output.txt
>
> real  0m1.788s
> user  0m1.736s
> sys   0m0.048s
>
> $ wc -lc long_output.txt 
>   99998 7699846 long_output.txt
> ```

Comment: А как собственно воспользоваться скриптом?

Comment: @riley69, в моём ответе три раза приводится командная строка, которая запускает скрипт. Я, к сожалению, не имею возможности поддерживать его пользователей. Извините. Полагаю, вам лучше обратится к программисту, который решит для вас эту задачу под ключ.